# Wrap text around image with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following HTML and CSS:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img.png">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Aenean est lectus, venenatis sit amet nisl sed, molestie 
    interdum elit. Proin maximus fermentum rhoncus. 
    Vestibulum blandit ligula ligula. Mauris volutpat cursus 
    enim eu iaculis. Duis condimentum ante sed dolor lacinia 
    imperdiet. Phasellus felis orci, dictum sed elit sed, 
    lobortis congue sem. Etiam at tortor diam. 
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { 
    font-family: Arial; 
}
.container {
    max-width: 500px;
    display: flex;
}
img {
    align-self: baseline;
}
p { 
    margin: 0 0 0 10px; 
}
```

This is what i get (current result):

[image: Current result]

I want to achieve the following without using float (desired result):

[image: Desired result]

What flex property can I use?

Comment: Did you reset base styles?
I tryed your code in codepen and is working as expected
[link]https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvaaKm

Comment: If you add more text it doesn't wrap around the image. That's my problem.

Comment: float is supposed to solve exactly your case, you can't achieve needed result with flex without ugly bicycles

Comment: I know it can be achieved easily with float. I wanted to know if there is a flex property that achieves that too.

Comment: with single property – no

Comment: [Here's](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/wrapping-text-around-image-using-flex-box/198288/4) what you need